# Write common elements of 2 csv files(having different no of columns) in a single file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have 2 csv files of the following format-

File1

```
David
Lennon
```

File2

```
David  0.3
Lennon 1.3
Wright 2.5
```

Desired Output-

```
David 0.3
Lennon 1.3
```

I am reading both csv files and then checking whether the same first column is present in file 2 or not and if present ,I want to keep it and then delete rest of them, but I don't know how to go to first element.

```
with open ('file1.csv') as h:
   an = h.readlines()
with open ('file2.csv') as n:
   non = n.readlines()

anno=[]
for i in an:
   anno.append(i.decode('utf-8').strip())

diff={}
for i in non:
   if i.decode('utf-8')[0].strip() in anno:
     diff[i[0]] = i[1]
```

I am getting the error in last line as I presume , it is not the right way to access first and second columns of the csv file.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so first of all, if you make use of the csv format, make sure you separate the values with commas (csv = comma separated values). So change file1 and file2 to this:

```
David
Lennon
```

and

```
David,0.3
Lennon,1.3
Wright,2.5
```

Okay so you want to get only the data names that are pressent in file1 out of file2 if I'm correct. I changed up the names of the variables to less cryptic names because I did not understand what you meant by them, but I kept the last Dictionary as diff (the desired output) for clarity.

Now Reading the names from file1 and put them in a list with readlines, however there is still some unwanted stuff in there the "\n". I replace the newline character with nothing in a for loop, after that creating a list from it, only the names will be left.

```
with open ("file1.csv") as file1:
   data_file1 = [name.replace("\n", "") for name in file1.readlines()]
```

For the file2 doing the same thing and creating a list splited by the comma so, "David, 0.3" becomes ["David", "0.3"]. Note that the type of the values is still a String.

```
with open ("file2.csv") as file1:
   data_file2 = [name.replace("\n", "").split(",") for name in file1.readlines()]
```

Now comparing the data from file1 and file2:

```
diff = {}
for line in data_file2:
    if line[0] in data_file1:
        diff[line[0]] = line[1]
```

Here line[0] is the name and line[1] the corresponding value for that name.

Now diff should return

```
>>> diff
{'David': '0.3', 'Lennon': '1.3'}
```

Cheers,
Jelle

Comment: You are awesome